# Значения поля ranges в device tree

Tags: любой-язык

Вот так выглядит описание узла pci в файле device tree.

```
  pci@0x10180000 {
        compatible = "arm,versatile-pci-hostbridge", "pci";
        reg = <0x10180000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <8 0>;
        bus-ranges = <0 0>;

        #address-cells = <3>
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges = <0x42000000 0 0x80000000 0x80000000 0 0x20000000
                  0x02000000 0 0xa0000000 0xa0000000 0 0x10000000
                  0x01000000 0 0x00000000 0xb0000000 0 0x01000000>;
    };
```

Как расшифровать/понять поля **address-cells**, **size-cells**, **ranges** для данного примера? Откуда взялись эти наборы цифр и что они означают?

Да, я знаю вот эту ссылку [сайт devicetree](http://www.devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage#PCI_Address_Translation), но к сожалению толи не понятно написано, или очень туп что более вероятно.

Спасибо